# UIActivityIndicatorView is bugged in the iPhoneSDK? (crashes from UIKit)

Tags: iphone

I got the following crash report from iTunesconnect. Is the UIActivityIndicatorView bugged?

```
Date/Time:       2009-09-26 12:33:02.034 +1000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d54964 lstat + 8
1   Foundation                      0x3055baf6 _NSFileExistsAtPath
2   Foundation                      0x3055f6a2 -[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]
3   WinterBoard.dylib               0x0019f034 0x19c000 + 12340
4   WinterBoard.dylib               0x001a032c 0x19c000 + 17196
5   UIKit                           0x30972650 +[UIActivityIndicatorView _loadResourcesForStyle:]
6   UIKit                           0x30972498 -[UIActivityIndicatorView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:]
7   UIKit                           0x309723bc -[UIActivityIndicatorView initWithFrame:]
8   UIKit                           0x30a113f8 -[UIActivityIndicatorView initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:]
```

Below is how I created it:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
act.center = CGPointMake(160, 190);
[act startAnimating];
[self addSubview:act];    
[act release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the log, it goes wrong with `-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]`. Below that line in the stack trace, you see that it was being called by `Winterboard.dylib`.

Winterboard is an application for jailbroken iPhones to modify the appearance of the OS which is not supported by Apple. In this case, Winterboard is to blame for the crash of your application, not UIKit.

You can't do anything about that, it's probably a bug in Winterboard which only users with a jailbroken iPhone and Winterboard may have.